# how to cancel nested request with rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

```
buttonClicked$.pipe(
switchMap(value=>makeRequest1),
switchMap(responseOfRequest1=>makeRequest2))
.subscribe()
```

I need to make 2 http request sequentially, and abort downstream pending request  if the button clicks. Is the above code the right approach? I understand that a new click will cancel pending `request1`. if the click happens during `request2`, does `request2` get canceled as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Why the second switchMap may not get cancelled

The `switchMap` operator cancels its inner Observable only when it receives the next event from its upstream Observable (i.e. `makeRequest1`), not when the source Observable emits (i.e. `buttonClicked$`). So consider the following sequence of events:

```
first button click
first request 1 sent
first response to request 1 received
first request 2 sent
second button click
second request 1 sent
first response to request 2 received
second response to request 1 received
```

In this scenario because the response to request 2 is received before the second response to request 1 is received, even though the second button click occurred before request 2 completed, request 2 was never cancelled.

If request 1 emits its second response before request 2 receives a response, then yes request 2 is cancelled. But note that it's not the button click that cancelled it per se, it's the emission of request 1 that cancelled it.

## The solution

If you wish to cancel both requests reliably when the button is clicked, then both requests need to be made within the same `switchMap`:

```
buttonClicked$.pipe(
  switchMap(clickValue => makeRequest1(clickValue).pipe(
    mergeMap(request1Value => makeRequest2(request1Value)))
).subscribe(request2Value => /* ... */);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is correct behavior because `switchMap` unsubscribes from its inner Observable only when it receives `next` notification. This means that when you have two `switchMap`s then the first one has to emit first to trigger unsubscription in the second one.

You can avoid this by using just one `switchMap` and putting the second `makeRequest2` call into a single chain with `makeRequest1`.

```
buttonClicked$.pipe(
  switchMap(value => makeRequest1(value).pipe(
    mergeMap(responseOfRequest1 => makeRequest2(responseOfRequest1)),
  )),
  .subscribe()
```

This way when `buttonClicked$` emits it makes `switchMap` unsubscribe from its inner Observable which internally unsubscribes also `mergeMap` that will cancel the second call if its still pending.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does work like that with interval. I didn't test it with network request.

On every click the second observable interval gets restarted.

```js
const { fromEvent, interval, of } = rxjs;
const { switchMap } = rxjs.operators;

const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const result = document.getElementById('result');
const click$ = fromEvent(btn, 'click');

click$
 .pipe(
   switchMap(value => of('Hello')),
   switchMap(value => interval(1000))
  )
  .subscribe(
   val => result.innerText = val
  )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.4.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>

<div id="result"></div>
```